# Parsing Json returns an error due to datatype

Tags: json, mongodb, parsing, mongodb-query

I am running a query in ASP.NET to get some data from collection in Mongo DB.
The query is running fine but the datatype that it is returning is different that i expect.

```
variable= Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<class>(var);
```

Data that it returns

I am using Newtonsoft to parse the Json:

variable is an object of class 
and var is the Json of the form > "{ \"Name\" : \"XYZ\", \"Value\" : [\"Value\"] }"
Class contains propeties Name and Value.
Exception it returns :
**{"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'Value', line 1, position 43."}**

Any Ideas how i should correct this.

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/s137ygkq/), that JSON is perfectly valid.

Comment: Again, it's perfectly valid JSON. What's the definition of `ResourceFieldName`? Specifically, does it have a `Value` property whose type is `string[]` (array of `string`)?